# Equivalent of Directory.CreateDirectory() in VB6

Tags: vb6

Trying to create several layers of folders at once C:\pie\applepie\recipies\
without using several different commands, is there an easy way similar to Directory.CreateDirectory()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's some code I used in one of my projects.  It requires a reference be added to the project for the file system object.

First, click Project -> References, scroll down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and select it.  Then you can use this function:

```
Public Sub MakePath(ByVal Folder As String)

    Dim arTemp() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim cFolder As String

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    arTemp = Split(Folder, "\")
    For i = LBound(arTemp) To UBound(arTemp)
        cFolder = cFolder & arTemp(i) & "\"
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(cFolder) Then
            Call FSO.CreateFolder(cFolder)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

'Without the need to reference FileSystemObject

```
Public Sub MkPath(ByVal sPath As String)
  Dim Splits() As String, CurFolder As String
  Dim i As Long
  Splits = Split(sPath, "\")
  For i = LBound(Splits) To UBound(Splits)
    CurFolder = CurFolder & Splits(i) & "\"
    If Dir(CurFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir CurFolder
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here is a function I wrote that takes a complete path including a drive letter if needed as a parameter. It then walks the path and traps the VB error number 76 (path not found). When the error handler traps an error 76 it creates the folder that caused the error and resumes walking the path.

```
    Public Function Check_Path(rsPath As String) As Boolean
        Dim dPath As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sProductName As String

        On Error GoTo Check_Path_Error

        If Left$(UCase$(rsPath), 2)  Left$(UCase$(CurDir), 2) Then
            ChDrive Left$(rsPath, 2)
        End If

        i = 3
        Do While InStr(i + 1, rsPath, "\") > 0
            dPath = Left$(rsPath, InStr(i + 1, rsPath, "\") - 1)
            i = InStr(i + 1, rsPath, "\")
            ChDir dPath
        Loop
        dPath = rsPath
        ChDir dPath

        Check_Path = True

    Exit Function

    Check_Path_Error:
        If Err.Number = 76 Then     'path not found'
            MkDir dPath             'create the folder'
        Resume
    Else
        sProductName = IIf(Len(App.ProductName) = 0, App.EXEName, App.ProductName)
        MsgBox "There was an unexpected error while verifying/creating directories." _
              & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description &  ".", _
            vbOKOnly + vbCritical, sProductName & " - Error Creating File"
        Check_Path = False
    End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet, another simple way to do it:

```
Public Sub MakePath(ByVal Path As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell "cmd /c mkdir """ & Path & """"
End Sub
```